# Launch pyspark Ipython notebook on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I just upgraded to Spark 2.0 from 1.4 and downloaded the ec2 directory from github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-2.0

To spin up some clusters I go to my ec2 directory and run these commands:

```
./spark-ec2 -k <keypair> -i <key-file> -s <num-slaves> launch <cluster-name>

./spark-ec2 -k <keypair> -i <key-file> login <cluster-name>
```

I have my clusters up and I'm logged into master but I don't know how to launch a pyspark notebook. With Spark 1.4 I'll run the command

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip=0.0.0.0" /root/spark/bin/pyspark --executor-memory 4G --driver-memory 4G &
```

and I have my notebook up and running fine but with Spark 2.0 there is no bin/pyspark directory. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source comments:

https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/master/bin/pyspark

> In Spark 2.0, IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed and pyspark fails
>   to launch if either option is set in the user's environment. Instead,
>   users should set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython  to use IPython and set
>   PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS to pass options when starting the Python
>   driver (e.g. PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook').  This supports
>   full customization of the IPython and executor Python executables.

The following [link](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297#.fm6gp3mcl) will take you step by step. Along with upgrading to Spark 2.0, you should also upgrade to Juypter Notebooks (formerly Ipython Notebooks) as well.

Comment: Does that mean I have to add the lines export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" to my .bash_profile?

Comment: Short answer Yes, but please see my edited Answer with a link to take you step by step. Take what you need disregard the rest.